# Optimize rendering Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I struggle with problem relayed on code (rendering) optimization.
I have 650 hexagons on screen and I need to move them all together and zoom them freely. 
As far I have 2d map that stores hexagon objects that contains some parameters as vertexes, center point etc. 
my onDraw method looks like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if(hexMap == null || hexMap.length <= 0) {
            populateHexMap();
        }
        if(radiusChanged) {
            changeRadius();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < hexMap.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < hexMap[i].length; j++) {
                if(hexMap[i][j] != null && hexMap[i][j].isToDraw()) {
                    paint.setColor(hexMap[i][j].getColor());
                    drawPath.rewind();
                    drawPath.moveTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(0).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(0).y);
                    drawPath.lineTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(1).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(1).y);
                    drawPath.lineTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(2).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(2).y);
                    drawPath.lineTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(3).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(3).y);
                    drawPath.lineTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(4).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(4).y);
                    drawPath.lineTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(5).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(5).y);
                    drawPath.lineTo(hexMap[i][j].getPoint(0).x, hexMap[i][j].getPoint(0).y);
                    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, paint);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Drawing works great as far. To zoom I catch pinch event gesture and change radius of hexagon then recalculate its vertexes. To move I simply add shift value to center points and recalculate vertexes.
Everything has worked great when I had for example ~30 hexagons. With 650 everything is super slow. 
I've tried to enable hardware acceleration but it didn't help. I've tried to reduce amount of `invalidate()` calls but in my opinion it's not the problem. The problem lays on `drawPath`.
Is there any way to speed things up? I don't have much time to switch on opengl right now or maybe you know some opensource solutions for drawing hexagons with opengl?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: drswLines should be faster than creating the Path over again and again

Comment: Yes, I have tried drawLines and it's faster but still not fast enough. Another problem with drawLines is that I need my hex to be filled with color and I don;t know how to achive that. Set paint style to fill doesn't work.